# Handle paths in variable names

Tags: angular, typescript

This code works locally but doesn't work when deployed due to the svg file not being found. Is there a better way to handle the file path in the variable?

```
        const svg = '../../../assets/images/myfile.svg';
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        const renderedCanvas =  await Canvg.from(context, svg);
```

Comment: Use environment variables if your bundler or whatever supports them

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you, consider using absolute paths from the root of your web application.

For example:

```
const svg = '/assets/images/myfile.svg';
```

or use Dynamic path resolution for Production environment to keep them different from locally

```
let svg;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  svg = '/assets/images/myfile.svg';
} else {
  svg = '../../../assets/images/myfile.svg';
}
```

Make sure you set correct environment path values (`process.env.NODE_ENV`)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing
`const svg = '../../../assets/images/myfile.svg';`
to
`const svg = './assets/images/myfile.svg';`